# c# MVC XML Record Value

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file:

```
<profiles>
  <profile username="user4" fullname="Full Name" />
 </profiles>
```

I am trying to retrive the value of the fullname, here is what I tried:

```
public List<string> GetFullName(string username)
{
    List<Profile> list = null;
    try
    {
        list = (from t in ProfileList
                where t.UserName == username
                select t).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    catch { }
    List<string> userFullName = new List<string>();
    if (list != null)
    {
        foreach (Profile t in list)
        {
            userFullName.Find(t.FullName);
        }
    }
    return userFullName;
}
```

FirstOrDefault gives an error!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dude, are you aware you have global variables in your code? Also, like the compiler, we can't infer the type of ProfileList.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault gives an error` Is that all? What is `ProfileList`? what error do you exactly get ?

Comment: @linkerro Actually the `ProfileList` type can be inferred by us. It should be `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` has a properties `UserName ` and `FullName`. ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather rewrite your code like this

```
    public String GetFullName(string username)
    {
        var targetObject = (from t in ProfileList
                    where t.UserName == username
                    select t).FirstOrDefault();

        if (targetObject != null) return targetObject.FullName;
        throw new Exception("Target user is not found");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`FirstOrDefault()` is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), which means that it's basically similar in concept to doing something like

```
var myList = new List<int>() { };
int myValue = StaticUtilsClass.FirstOrDefault(myList);
```

Now, if you look at [FirstOrDefault documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx%5C), notice that it throws a null argument exception when you pass in a null parameter.

What this means is that

```
List<int> myList = null;
myList.FirstOrDefault();
```

will throw an exception.

So, anytime you call `x.FirstOrDefault()`, and encounter a problem (i.e. an "error") the first thing to check is whether x, in this case, your query, is returning null.

From there, I would take a look at the fact that `FirstOrDefault()` is going to return a single entity, but you're setting it equal to a `List<Profile>`.  Unless your ProfileList is an enumeration of `List<Profile>`, that's going to be a problem as well.

That should get you started anyway.  Beyond that, it'd be helpful to know what ProfileList is and where it's declared.